# How to get the user date when every HTTP request is made

Tags: jakarta-ee, http-headers

Is it possible to get the date of every HTTP Request in java?

Somthing like :

```
request.getDateHeader(THE-USER-DATE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the time(zone) of the user calling your service. This is not provided in any HTTP Header field.

If you're running a WebPage you may however get the current time of the user by java script and make it parameter attached to the initial request.